# CanCan Access Block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm working on a Rails 4 app that uses CanCan to grant access to users and I'm working on a can block but it doesn't seem that well written, i guess its pseudo code, its how i would like the ability to work. Can it be changed to work better or more efficient? I'm also trying to avoid unnecessary quires that could make the request take longer to process.

```
can :manage, User do |u|
  u.id.eql?(user.id) || u.account.founders.includes(u) || u.account.collaborators.includes(u)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost got the right code here already. Here's how I'd do it:

```
can :manage, User do |u|
  u.id == user.id ||
  u.account.founders.exists?(u.id) ||
  u.account.collaborators.exists?(u.id)
end
```

Comparing using `==` is the standard in Ruby. `eql?` is rarely used.

The `exists?` method will perform a lightweight database query and returns `true` if the database does contain that ID within those records. How you were doing it before was wrong, because `includes` is an ActiveRecord method for eagerly loading associations. Even if you used the similarly named `include?` method, it still would've loaded all the founders and collaborators for the account, and then used Ruby to check to see if those collections contained that user.